# plotting vertical lines in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I have a list such as here:

`list1 = {{-(5/4), 3}, {-(3/4), 2}, {1/4, 6}, {3/4, 5}};`

My desire is to have a plot similar to (just in shape not in data)
[image]

however when I use of ListLinePlot, I just get a plot same as :
[image]

I guess I have to insert some zeros between my main data in list? if it is correct, how many zeros are needed?

Comment: Does the option `Filling -> Axis` not do what you want? It's the very first example in the `ListPlot` documentation.

Comment: Yes, But it doesn't satisfy all aim, because Filling just plots lines bellow points, I wanted to have zero horizontal line at the bottom of the plot as the first plot.

Comment: If it gets more complicated than this (I'm thinking of the horizontal red line), you can also build the graphics directly from `Line` primitives.  Working with graphics primitives in Mathematica is easier than one might imagine. :-) http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphicsAndSoundOverview.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider setting a custom gridline:

```
ListPlot[list1, PlotStyle -> White, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], GridLines -> {None, {0}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

The one difference from your picture is that a gridline goes all the way across the plot area. If it is important to you that the horizontal line ends at the extremes of your data set, then the following alternative might be what you want:

```
ListPlot[list1, PlotStyle -> White, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Red, Line[{{-5/4, 0}, {3/4, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

I would note that `ListLinePlot` is *designed* to join the points together; it is equivalent to `ListPlot` with the `Joined` option set to `True`. If you want disjoint points, you need `ListPlot`, with the `Joined` option set to `False`, which is the default.

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {{-(5/4), 3}, {-(3/4), 2}, {1/4, 6}, {3/4, 5}};
xLim = {Min[#], Max[#]} &[list1[[All, 1]]];

zeroLine = Plot[0, {x,Min@xLim, Max@xLim}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
    listPlot = ListPlot[list1, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Show[zeroLine, listPlot, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]